# How to Change Redraw widget from a Dialogbox?

Tags: python, pyside

I am pretty new with coding in PySide and have run in to trouble. I am building a small Widget which draws Labels on the Screen.

I have started with fridgemagnets examples. I would like to know how to updated the color of the fridgemangent from the dialog box.

Thanks in advance.

```
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

import fridgemagnets_rc

class PropertyChangeWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    " Property Change Window"
    def __init__(self, magnet_text, parent=None):

        super(PropertyChangeWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.block = magnet_text
        self.setWindowTitle("Properties of " + magnet_text)
        self.setMinimumSize(160, 160)

        buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel)

        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)


    def accept(self):
        self.hide()

        print ("Change Magnet Color to Green")
        print ("Redraw all Magnets")


class DragLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text, parent):
        super(DragLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.text = text

        metric = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font())
        size = metric.size(QtCore.Qt.TextSingleLine, text)

        image = QtGui.QImage(size.width() + 12, size.height() + 12,
                QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied)
        image.fill(QtGui.qRgba(0, 0, 0, 0))

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.ForceOutline)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(image)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.blue)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(QtCore.QRectF(0.1, 0.1, image.width()-1,
                image.height()-1), 25, 25, QtCore.Qt.RelativeSize)

        painter.setFont(font)
        painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
        painter.drawText(QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(6, 6), size),
                QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter, text)
        painter.end()

        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))
        self.labelText = text

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        itemData = QtCore.QByteArray()
        dataStream = QtCore.QDataStream(itemData, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        dataStream << QtCore.QByteArray(str(self.labelText)) << QtCore.QPoint(event.pos() - self.rect().topLeft())

        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimeData.setData('application/x-fridgemagnet', itemData)
        mimeData.setText(self.labelText)

        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setHotSpot(event.pos() - self.rect().topLeft())
        drag.setPixmap(self.pixmap())

        self.hide()

        if drag.exec_(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction | QtCore.Qt.CopyAction, QtCore.Qt.CopyAction) == QtCore.Qt.MoveAction:
            self.close()
        else:
            self.show()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self._clickevent == "Single Click":
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(400, self.performSingleClickAction)
        else:
            self._clickevent = "Double Click"

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        self._clickevent = "Double Click"
        self.new_window = PropertyChangeWindow(self.text)
        self.new_window.show()


class DragWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DragWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        dictionaryFile = QtCore.QFile(':/dictionary/words.txt')
        dictionaryFile.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)

        x = 5
        y = 5

        for word in QtCore.QTextStream(dictionaryFile).readAll().split():
            wordLabel = DragLabel(word, self)
            wordLabel.move(x, y)
            wordLabel.show()
            x += wordLabel.width() + 2
            if x >= 245:
                x = 5
                y += wordLabel.height() + 2

        newPalette = self.palette()
        newPalette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.setPalette(newPalette)

        self.setMinimumSize(400, max(200, y))
        self.setWindowTitle("Fridge Magnets")
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat('application/x-fridgemagnet'):
            if event.source() in self.children():
                event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
                event.accept()
            else:
                event.acceptProposedAction()
        elif event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.acceptProposedAction()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    dragMoveEvent = dragEnterEvent

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat('application/x-fridgemagnet'):
            mime = event.mimeData()
            itemData = mime.data('application/x-fridgemagnet')
            dataStream = QtCore.QDataStream(itemData, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)

            text = QtCore.QByteArray()
            offset = QtCore.QPoint()
            dataStream >> text >> offset

            try:
                # Python v3.
                text = str(text, encoding='latin1')
            except TypeError:
                # Python v2.
                text = str(text)

            newLabel = DragLabel(text, self)
            newLabel.move(event.pos() - offset)
            newLabel.show()

            if event.source() in self.children():
                event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
                event.accept()
            else:
                event.acceptProposedAction()
        elif event.mimeData().hasText():
            pieces = event.mimeData().text().split()
            position = event.pos()

            for piece in pieces:
                newLabel = DragLabel(piece, self)
                newLabel.move(position)
                newLabel.show()

                position += QtCore.QPoint(newLabel.width(), 0)

            event.acceptProposedAction()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == '__main__':

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DragWidget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Answer (score 0):

Each class has a task, in this case the best thing is that PropertyChangeWindow does not change the color but returns a color, and in the DragLabel change its color using the previous information.

If you analyze your initial code you will notice that QDataStream stores relevant information such as text and position, to this we must also add the QColor.

Considering the above the solution is:

```py
from PySide import QtCore, QtGui

import fridgemagnets_rc


class PropertyChangeWindow(QtGui.QDialog):
    " Property Change Window"

    def __init__(self, magnet_text, parent=None):

        super(PropertyChangeWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.block = magnet_text
        self.setWindowTitle("Properties of " + magnet_text)
        self.setMinimumSize(160, 160)

        buttonBox = QtGui.QDialogButtonBox(
            QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Ok | QtGui.QDialogButtonBox.Cancel
        )

        buttonBox.accepted.connect(self.accept)
        buttonBox.rejected.connect(self.reject)

        mainLayout = QtGui.QVBoxLayout()
        mainLayout.addWidget(buttonBox)
        self.setLayout(mainLayout)
        self.m_color = QtGui.QColor()

    def accept(self):
        self.m_color = QtGui.QColor("green")
        super(PropertyChangeWindow, self).accept()

    @property
    def color(self):
        return self.m_color


class DragLabel(QtGui.QLabel):
    def __init__(self, text, color=QtGui.QColor(QtCore.Qt.blue), parent=None):
        super(DragLabel, self).__init__(parent)
        self.labelText = text
        self.color = color
        self.redraw()

    def redraw(self):
        metric = QtGui.QFontMetrics(self.font())
        size = metric.size(QtCore.Qt.TextSingleLine, self.labelText)

        image = QtGui.QImage(
            size.width() + 12,
            size.height() + 12,
            QtGui.QImage.Format_ARGB32_Premultiplied,
        )
        image.fill(QtGui.qRgba(0, 0, 0, 0))

        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setStyleStrategy(QtGui.QFont.ForceOutline)

        painter = QtGui.QPainter()
        painter.begin(image)
        painter.setRenderHint(QtGui.QPainter.Antialiasing)
        painter.setBrush(self.color)
        painter.drawRoundedRect(
            QtCore.QRectF(0.1, 0.1, image.width() - 1, image.height() - 1),
            25,
            25,
            QtCore.Qt.RelativeSize,
        )

        painter.setFont(font)
        painter.setBrush(QtCore.Qt.black)
        painter.drawText(
            QtCore.QRect(QtCore.QPoint(6, 6), size),
            QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter,
            self.labelText,
        )
        painter.end()

        self.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap.fromImage(image))

    def mousePressEvent(self, event):
        itemData = QtCore.QByteArray()
        dataStream = QtCore.QDataStream(itemData, QtCore.QIODevice.WriteOnly)
        dataStream << QtCore.QByteArray(str(self.labelText)) << QtCore.QPoint(
            event.pos() - self.rect().topLeft()
        )
        dataStream << self.color

        mimeData = QtCore.QMimeData()
        mimeData.setData("application/x-fridgemagnet", itemData)
        mimeData.setText(self.labelText)

        drag = QtGui.QDrag(self)
        drag.setMimeData(mimeData)
        drag.setHotSpot(event.pos() - self.rect().topLeft())
        drag.setPixmap(self.pixmap())

        self.hide()

        if (
            drag.exec_(
                QtCore.Qt.MoveAction | QtCore.Qt.CopyAction,
                QtCore.Qt.CopyAction,
            )
            == QtCore.Qt.MoveAction
        ):
            self.close()
        else:
            self.show()

    def mouseReleaseEvent(self, event):
        if self._clickevent == "Single Click":
            QtCore.QTimer.singleShot(400, self.performSingleClickAction)
        else:
            self._clickevent = "Double Click"

    def mouseDoubleClickEvent(self, event):
        self._clickevent = "Double Click"
        new_window = PropertyChangeWindow(self.labelText)
        if new_window.exec_() == QtGui.QDialog.Accepted:
            self.color = new_window.color
            self.redraw()


class DragWidget(QtGui.QWidget):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(DragWidget, self).__init__(parent)

        dictionaryFile = QtCore.QFile(":/dictionary/words.txt")
        dictionaryFile.open(QtCore.QFile.ReadOnly)

        x = 5
        y = 5

        for word in QtCore.QTextStream(dictionaryFile).readAll().split():
            wordLabel = DragLabel(word, parent=self)
            wordLabel.move(x, y)
            wordLabel.show()
            x += wordLabel.width() + 2
            if x >= 245:
                x = 5
                y += wordLabel.height() + 2

        newPalette = self.palette()
        newPalette.setColor(QtGui.QPalette.Window, QtCore.Qt.white)
        self.setPalette(newPalette)

        self.setMinimumSize(400, max(200, y))
        self.setWindowTitle("Fridge Magnets")
        self.setAcceptDrops(True)

    def dragEnterEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/x-fridgemagnet"):
            if event.source() in self.children():
                event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
                event.accept()
            else:
                event.acceptProposedAction()
        elif event.mimeData().hasText():
            event.acceptProposedAction()
        else:
            event.ignore()

    dragMoveEvent = dragEnterEvent

    def dropEvent(self, event):
        if event.mimeData().hasFormat("application/x-fridgemagnet"):
            mime = event.mimeData()
            itemData = mime.data("application/x-fridgemagnet")
            dataStream = QtCore.QDataStream(itemData, QtCore.QIODevice.ReadOnly)

            text = QtCore.QByteArray()
            offset = QtCore.QPoint()
            color = QtGui.QColor()
            dataStream >> text >> offset >> color

            try:
                # Python v3.
                text = str(text, encoding="latin1")
            except TypeError:
                # Python v2.
                text = str(text)

            newLabel = DragLabel(text, color, self)
            newLabel.move(event.pos() - offset)
            newLabel.show()

            if event.source() in self.children():
                event.setDropAction(QtCore.Qt.MoveAction)
                event.accept()
            else:
                event.acceptProposedAction()
        elif event.mimeData().hasText():
            pieces = event.mimeData().text().split()
            position = event.pos()

            for piece in pieces:
                newLabel = DragLabel(piece, self)
                newLabel.move(position)
                newLabel.show()

                position += QtCore.QPoint(newLabel.width(), 0)

            event.acceptProposedAction()
        else:
            event.ignore()


if __name__ == "__main__":

    import sys

    app = QtGui.QApplication(sys.argv)
    window = DragWidget()
    window.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

Comment: Thanks for the quick answer. This really solved my problem.